# Python PLT ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have been trying to reproduce the comparison with the google trends file from Wilkonhrsen Additive Models (https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/tree/master/additive_models), but I keep getting this error and I have not been able to figure out what exactly is the problem, is it related to the data type of the tesla_chnagepoints data values?
Code

```
tesla_search = pd.read_csv('data/tesla_search_terms.csv') # Convert month to a 
datetime tesla_search['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(tesla_search['Month']) 
tesla_changepoints = [str(date) for date in tesla_prophet.changepoints] 
plt.plot(tesla_search['Month'], tesla_search['Search'], label = 'Searches') 
plt.vlines(tesla_changepoints, ymin = 0, ymax= 100, colors = 'r', linewidth=0.6, 
linestyles = 'dashed', label = 'Changepoints') 
plt.grid('off'); 
plt.ylabel('Relative Search Freq'); 
plt.legend() 
plt.title('Tesla Search Terms and Changepoints');
```

Thanks in advance,

```
File "/Users/ManuelRivera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1553, in convert_units
f'units: {x!r}') from e

ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['2010-09-27 00:00:00', '2010-12-27 00:00:00', '2011-03-25 00:00:00', '2011-06-23 00:00:00', '2011-09-22 00:00:00', '2011-12-20 00:00:00', '2012-03-21 00:00:00', '2012-06-20 00:00:00', '2012-09-18 00:00:00', '2012-12-18 00:00:00', '2013-03-21 00:00:00', '2013-06-19 00:00:00', '2013-09-17 00:00:00', '2013-12-13 00:00:00', '2014-03-18 00:00:00', '2014-06-16 00:00:00', '2014-09-12 00:00:00', '2014-12-11 00:00:00', '2015-03-13 00:00:00', '2015-06-11 00:00:00', '2015-09-10 00:00:00', '2015-12-08 00:00:00', '2016-03-09 00:00:00', '2016-06-08 00:00:00', '2016-09-06 00:00:00']
```

Comment: can you show the code that is producing this error

Comment: tesla_search = pd.read_csv('data/tesla_search_terms.csv')
# Convert month to a datetime
    tesla_search['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(tesla_search['Month'])
    tesla_changepoints = [str(date) for date in tesla_prophet.changepoints]

    plt.plot(tesla_search['Month'], tesla_search['Search'], label = 'Searches')
    plt.vlines(tesla_changepoints, ymin = 0, ymax= 100, colors = 'r', linewidth=0.6, linestyles = 'dashed', label = 'Changepoints')
   plt.grid('off'); plt.ylabel('Relative Search Freq'); plt.legend()
   plt.title('Tesla Search Terms and Changepoints');